# Cassandra 3.0.12 - nofile limit adequate? : false

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, ubuntu-14.04

I have a Cassandra 3.0.12 cluster that complains about nofile limit adequate? : false when starting. I've tripple checked all my settings that are recommended via datastax, and verified the limit, output shown below.

Anyone have any idea how I can get out of degraded mode?

WARN  [main] 2017-04-01 02:40:29,608 SigarLibrary.java:174 - Cassandra server running in degraded mode. Is swap disabled? : true,  Address space adequate? : true,  nofile limit adequate? : false, nproc limit adequate? : true

```
ubuntu@stg-cassandra-1:~$ cat /proc/5777/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             63790                63790                processes
Max open files            100000               100000               files
Max locked memory         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       63790                63790                signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the test result, you will need to take the appropriate action:

**Is swap disabled?** You can follow the instructions to disable swap, as explained [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/684771/best-way-to-disable-swap-in-linux)

- Identify configured swap devices and files with cat /proc/swaps.
- Turn off all swap devices and files with swapoff -a.
- Remove any matching reference found in /etc/fstab.
- Optional: Destroy any swap devices or files found in step 1 to prevent their reuse. Due to your concerns about leaking sensitive information, you may wish to consider performing some sort of secure wipe.

**Address space adequate?** This refers to the disk space available in the node, [Datastax's guidelines](http://docs.datastax.com/en/dse-planning/doc/planning/planningHardware.html#planningHardware__disk) is quite useful here

**nofile limit adequate?** Verify that you have set in */etc/security/limits.d/cassandra.conf* the values:

```
cassandra - memlock unlimited 
cassandra - nofile 100000 
cassandra - nproc 32768
cassandra - as unlimited
```

**nproc limit adequate?** Verify that there is the following entry in */etc/sysctl.conf*:

```
vm.max_map_count = 131072
```

Ensure to restart the box if you need to modify the configuration files.

Comment: Hey, Carlos - thanks for taking the time to reply to my question. It is very specific to the nofile limit. And I showed that my system has the appropirate values set, however it remains in degraded mode. Here is the cassandra.conf file contents:  

ubuntu@prd-cassandra-1b:~$ cat /etc/security/limits.d/cassandra.conf
# Provided by the cassandra package
cassandra  -  memlock  unlimited
cassandra  -  nofile   100000
cassandra  -  as       unlimited
cassandra  -  nproc    8096

Comment: Hi Drew, just to confirm, are you executing the service with the `Cassandra` user? if you are executing it as root, you may need to also set those settings for the root user, as explained [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/troubleshooting/trblshootInsufficientResources_r.html). Also, you will need to restart the box or execute `sudo sysctl -p` to ensure that the new setting is used. Beside these warnings, are you getting any other errors in your cluster?

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for the reply. I can confirm I am running the service as the cassandra user. "cassand+  2860  2.6 89.5 17946252 14713212 ?   SLl  Apr07 7431:09 java -Xloggc:/var/log/cassandra/gc.log"....  The servers have been restarted a number of times as well. No other issues evident.